# rails, how to pass my collection_select value to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I need the form's selected value to be passed to my controller one way or another. I am unsure what do i put in route and controller to get the value.

**show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Report#show</h1>

<%= form_tag new_report_path(:cname) do %>
  <label for="lookup">Lookup</label>
  <%= collection_select(:cname, 2, Company.all, :id, :name) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller   report_controller.rb**

```
def show
end

def add 
  # how do i get the :cname here?
end
```

**Route**

```
  root 'report#show'
  get '/report/index' => 'report#show'
```

**What i tested?**
I tested my code and it gave me this url.

Current Result : http://localhost:3000/report/new.cname

Expected Result  :   http://localhost:3000/report/:cname

********UPDATE******

I tested out widjajayd's solution.
And it returned this error back to me..
I also just provided the controller name here
[image]

Here is my rake routes as well

> ```
>                add_reports POST       /reports/add(.:format)                    reports#add
>                    reports GET        /reports(.:format)                        reports#index
>                            POST       /reports(.:format)                        reports#create
>                 new_report GET        /reports/new(.:format)                    reports#new
>                edit_report GET        /reports/:id/edit(.:format)               reports#edit
>                     report GET        /reports/:id(.:format)                    reports#show
>                            PATCH      /reports/:id(.:format)                    reports#update
>                            PUT        /reports/:id(.:format)                    reports#update
>                            DELETE     /reports/:id(.:format)                    reports#destroy
>              company_index GET        /company(.:format)                        company#index
>                            POST       /company(.:format)                        company#create
>                new_company GET        /company/new(.:format)                    company#new
>               edit_company GET        /company/:id/edit(.:format)               company#edit
>                    company GET        /company/:id(.:format)                    company#show
>                            PATCH      /company/:id(.:format)                    company#update
>                            PUT        /company/:id(.:format)                    company#update
>                            DELETE     /company/:id(.:format)                    company#destroy
>                       root GET        /                                         report#show
> ```

Comment: Your links won't work, as its a `localhost`!

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: it obviously won't work ... i havent deloyed it... @Pavan

Answer (score 1):

here is some correction about your code above

your routes.rb

```
resources :reports do
  collection {
    post :add
  }
end
```

your show.html.erb,
**this is edited version after you reported an error, actually just removed the " (...)" see form_tag**

```
<%= form_tag add_reports_path, :method => 'post' do  %>
  <label for="lookup">Lookup</label>
  <%= collection_select(:cname, 2, Company.all, :id, :name) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

your controller (I created collection inside routes)

```
def add 
  your_cname = params[:cname]
end
```

you may check for custom route for rails get and passing data  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871072/rails-create-file-and-render/44871333#44871333)

Comment: Hi , thanks for your help! 
I tried this out, it returned an error. will post above.

Comment: Ok sorry for the problem, I corrected my answer and I have tested the answer above in my system , I can get the params[:cname] as your requested